# Apply existing reference to CanvasRendingContext2D to an element

Tags: javascript, caching, canvas

I am trying to store a canvas reference in a global object and then apply that reference to an element instead of regenerating the canvas. here is my existing code. I hope that makes sense. thanks in advance!

*waveformCache is assumed to be a global*

```
var cL = document.getElementById('track' + trackId + 'WaveformL');
var cR = document.getElementById('track' + trackId + 'WaveformR');

if (waveformCache.hasOwnProperty(track.path))
{
    var waveformCacheItem = waveformCache[track.path];

    if (waveformCacheItem.hasOwnProperty('left'))
    {
        // restore canvas data here to cL element
    }
}
else
{
    waveformCache[track.path] = {};

    var left = track.data.getChannelData(0);

    var ctx1 = cL.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.save();
    ctx1.strokeStyle = 'rgb(49,73,11)';
    ctx1.translate(0, 55/2); //centers where the line drawing starts horizontally

    for(var i = 0; i < left.length; i += 200) {
        var x1 = Math.floor(track.waveformLength * i / left.length); //first parameter affects the length of the drawn waveform #ZOOM
        var y1 = left[i] * 55/2;

        ctx1.beginPath();
        ctx1.moveTo(x1, 0);
        ctx1.lineTo(x1 + 1, y1);
        ctx1.stroke();
    }
    ctx1.restore();

    waveformCache[track.path].left = ctx1;
}
```

Comment: And what's your problem ?

Comment: @Kaiido I am not sure how to reapply the canvas to the element when retrieving the CanvasRendingContext2D object from the "waveformCache". `// restore canvas data here to cL element`

Comment: You mean the canvas element? It's stored in the context's .canvas property

Answer (score 1):

**An outline of how to serialize an html5 canvas CanvasRendingContext2D**

The canvas context (CanvasRendingContext2D ) holds the canvas' properties (styling, current transformation, etc).

**Important!** The context does not hold all the executed drawing commands that created the canvas content. 
*Context Properties:*

- **Coloring:** strokeStyle, fillStyle(1), globalAlpha,
- **Line styles:** lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin, miterLimit,
- **Text Styles:** font, textAlign, textBaseline,
- **Compositing:** globalCompositeOperation,
- **Shadowing:** shadowColor, shadowBlur, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY

(1) `fillStyle` is usually a string ('#ff0000'), but it can alternatively hold a reference to a gradient object or pattern object. To save the context's fillStyle, you will have to either ignore gradients / patterns or also serialize the gradient / pattern properties.

**Here's how to save context properties into an object**

```
var properties=['strokeStyle','lineWidth','font','globalAlpha',
    'globalCompositeOperation','shadowColor','shadowBlur',
    'shadowOffsetX','shadowOffsetY','lineCap','lineJoin',
    'miterLimit','textAlign','textBaseline'];

var serializedContext={}

for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++){
    var prop=properties[i];
    serializedContext[prop]=context[prop];
}

// fillStyle can be a headache
if(typeof context.fillStyle === 'string'){
    serializedContext['fillStyle']=context.fillStyle;
}else{
    // do lots more work to serialize gradient or pattern :-O
}
```

**Here's how to copy saved context properties into a new context:**

```
var context=myOtherCanvas.getContext('2d');

for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++){
    var prop=properties[i];
    context[prop]=serializedContext[prop];
}

// fillStyle can be a headache
if(typeof context.fillStyle === 'string'){
    serializedContext['fillStyle']=context.fillStyle;
}else{
    // do lots more work to re-establish gradient or pattern :-O
}
```

**Re-executing the drawings**

If you want to re-execute all the drawings commands, you must save the commands and their arguments.

From your example code, it looks like your drawings involve line segments(`moveTo` & `lineTo`) so you can save each segment as a segment-object in an array of segment-objects.

```
var segments=[];

segments.push({moveX:10, moveY:20, lineX:100, lineY:35});

... and push all the other line segments
```

And then you can "replay" the line-segment drawing commands after you've reset all the context properties:

```
// redraw every line segment
ctx.beginPath()
for(var i=0;i<segments.length;i++){
    var s=segments[i];
    ctx.moveTo(s.moveX,s.moveY);
    ctx.lineTo(s.lineX,s.lineY);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

You can also serialize and replay all the common drawing commands (arc, beginPath, bezierCurveTo , clearRect, clip, closePath, fill, fillRect, fillText, lineTo, moveTo, quadraticCurveTo, rect, restore, rotate, save, scale, setTransform, stroke, strokeRect, strokeText, transform, translate). Save each command name & associated arguments in an object and save all those command-objects in an array.

These commands return values so you will need to do more work to handle them: 
measureText, getImageData (putImageData), toDataURL, isPointInPath, isPointInStroke, createImageData, createLinearGradient, createRadialGradient, createPattern. Luckily, these commands are used are used less often than the more common (simpler) commands.

**About portability**

If you use this method of saving all properties & drawing commands into object arrays, you can easily serialize them all into JSON strings with `JSON.stringify` and you can easily deserialize them back into object arrays with `JSON.parse`.

Having your canvas properties & drawing commands serialized to strings means that you can easily transport them to a server for storage and then fetch them for replaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Path2D` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) to store your paths commands at. Then store the path in your global object. When you need to re-apply the path, simply stroke or fill using the stored path object.

**For example:**

```
var path = new Path2D();

...
path.moveTo(.. , ..);
path.lineTo(.. , ..);
etc.
```

Later when you need to recall the path:

```
ctx.stroke(path);
```

(A bonus is that you can initialize it using [SVG paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D#Using_SVG_paths). This means you can just define your path using SVG commands and store that as a single string. Reapply using the route of Path2D at a slight cost of performance when initializing.)

`Path2D` can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) for browsers which do not yet support it (see notes for special cases).