# Can I save a HTML5 canvas drawing to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with some drawings on it, e.g. stroke, arc, and rect, and I want to save the drawings on the canvas to a Javascript variable that can be used again to restore the canvas drawings onto another canvas.

Is this possible?

Comment: Basic stuff -- you really should have Googled it. **Save:** `var url=canvasElement.toDataURL()`, **Restore:** `var img=new Image(); img.onload=function(){otherContext.drawImage(img,0,0);}; img.src=url`

Comment: @markE I think OP is more after a canvas path commands serializer, I also think I remember you had a link for it. And if not, there is no apparent need to pass through `toDataURL` + `img` + `drawImage`, `ctx2.drawImage(canvas1)` is probably enough.

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks--You have sharp eyes to read that from the Q! :-) [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368722/apply-existing-reference-to-canvasrendingcontext2d-to-an-element/36369364#36369364) the start of a context command serializer

Comment: @markE, I have to admit it's just suppositions, this Q is really unclear to me too...

Answer (score 3):

You can, simply using [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL(type)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), then draw it creating a new [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image), pointing its source to the saved data as string.

Alternative: get image data using [CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData(x, y, width, height)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData), then drawing it using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData(ImageData)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData).

In another case, you'll need to make every drawing points as object tokens. If you specify that in your question, I update the answer.